# Script refuse to work with a certain location path structure when uploading photos

Tags: php

I have this script that uploads a photo to a folder call images and it also stores the photo's location in the database.

It works perfectly with this method

```
$id_photo_test = explode('.', $_FILES['id_photo']['name']);
        $id_photo_ext = end($id_photo_test);
        $id_photo_prefix= 'applicant';
        $id_photo_file_name = $id_photo_prefix . uniqid() . '.' . $id_photo_ext;
        $id_photo_directory = 'images/';
        $id_photo_location = $id_photo_directory.$id_photo_file_name;  
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['id_photo']['tmp_name'], $id_photo_location);
        $id_photo= $id_photo_location;
```

I'm just curious why I can't do this with this second method with out getting any errors

```
$id_photo_test = explode('.', $_FILES['id_photo']['name']);
    $id_photo_ext = end($id_photo_test);
    $id_photo_prefix= 'applicant';
    $id_photo_file_name = $id_photo_prefix . uniqid() . '.' . $id_photo_ext;
    $id_photo_directory = '/it/webcam/member/images/';
    $id_photo_location = $id_photo_directory.$id_photo_file_name;  
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['id_photo']['tmp_name'], $id_photo_location);//<-line 84
    $id_photo= $id_photo_location;
```

these are the errors that I am getting with this second method

Error 1:

Warning: move_uploaded_file(/it/webcam/member/images/applicant5b204464aaba4.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\it\webcam\member\submit-db-insert-and-response.php on line 84

Error 2:

Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move 'C:\xampp\tmp\php7BAC.tmp' to '/it/webcam/member/images/applicant5b204464aaba4.jpg' in C:\xampp\htdocs\it\webcam\member\submit-db-insert-and-response.php on line 84

I basically need the second methods structure so I can use this structure to see the photos on another section of this site in a image tag for example

```
<img src='using php and mysqli to get the photo stored location from the db'>
```

which looks like this when viewing this in a public source code viewer

```
<img src='/it/webcam/member/images/applicant5b204464aaba4.jpg'>
```

so how can I do that? I tried to use the solutions from google and this site to solve my problem but those sources are not working.

Comment: You could've just said that you changed the target directory.

Comment: `No such file or directory` means it cannot find the target directory. removed the leading `/` from `'/it/webcam/member/images/';`

Comment: hungrykoala your advice did not work $id_photo_directory = 'it/webcam/member/images/'; just keep in mind they are submitting the photos from a form located at /it/webcam/member/submit.php and they are using submit-db-insert-and-response.php to do the server stuff here is the errors I am getting now

Comment: Warning: move_uploaded_file(it/webcam/member/images/applicant5b20855274535.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\it\webcam\member\submit-db-insert-and-response.php on line 84
Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move 'C:\xampp\tmp\php468A.tmp' to 'it/webcam/member/images/applicant5b20855274535.jpg' in C:\xampp\htdocs\it\webcam\member\submit-db-insert-and-response.php on line 84

Comment: The reason for that is it can't find the directory. You'll need to specify the full path to it. You're basically asking PHP to insert the directory to `/it/webcam/member/it/webcam/member/images/` since you're running the code inside `/it/webcam/member/`. Or you can just use `images/` as you previously did.

Comment: I can't use images even do it works I have a section that is a section where we admins can see the photos at /it/webcam/member/it/webcam/admin/applications-view/ so using that in a image tag will look like this <img src='images/example.png'> in other words I don't have a folder in the the admin section call images and I don't want that I just want to know how I can do this by getting the whole file path with out errors because I am not planing on moving the images folder

Comment: move_uploaded_file() expects an existing directory, otherwise you can create it first with mkdir()

Answer (score 0):

Since the php file you are running is located in `C:\xampp\htdocs\it\webcam\member`, move_uploaded_file() will start from there and at the end `id_photo_directory` will be  `C:\xampp\htdocs\it\webcam\member\images`

The reason why you are having problems in the second code is that you are adding an absolute path (/it/...) and it can't be found. The system will start searching for that path from the beginning, like C:\ or D:.

What you can do is add something like

```
$id_photo_directory = '../some-other-images';
```

so your new path will be `C:\xampp\htdocs\it\webcam\some-other-images`

The two dots means one folder up (/../), so you will now be able to go wherever you want.

---

You need to create the directory first:

```
$id_photo_test = explode('.', $_FILES['id_photo']['name']);
$id_photo_ext = end($id_photo_test);
$id_photo_prefix= 'applicant';
$id_photo_file_name = $id_photo_prefix . uniqid() . '.' . $id_photo_ext;
$id_photo_directory = 'it/webcam/member/images/';

if(!is_dir($id_photo_directory)) {
    mkdir($id_photo_directory, 0777, true);
}

$id_photo_location = $id_photo_directory.$id_photo_file_name;  
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['id_photo']['tmp_name'], $id_photo_location);//<-line 84
$id_photo= $id_photo_location;
```

Your new path will be C:\xampp\htdocs\it\webcam\member\it/webcam/member/images/

Comment: hey thanks for your advice and your response and did you mean like this $id_photo_directory = '../images';  remember the /images is a folder I am referencing to and if you did mean that it gave the same results :(

Comment: Thanks for trying to help out me out It did not give me any errors but now I can't get any images to appear in the images folder :( but it did store the path in the database but I had to change a section of your code $id_photo_directory = 'it/webcam/member/images/'; to this $id_photo_directory = '/it/webcam/member/images/'; because your code was storing the path like this it/webcam/member/images/ in the db so I added this / so it can be like this in the database /it/webcam/member/images/  so how can I get the images to appear again in the images folder :(?

Comment: Hmm, is C:\xampp\htdocs\it\webcam\member\images empty? None of the answers removed anything as far as I know.

Comment: Yes now I lost the ability to have images appear there now :(

Comment: No images appear any more

Comment: I'll get back to you soon I think I know why

Comment: never mind i'm back so why do you think I can't upload images any more? :( jose?

Comment: Revert every change you made, leave your code like when you were about to post this question and run it, what error does show up?

Comment: it only works perfectly with  $id_photo_directory = 'images/'; which is limited to only storing that not in a path I can't just use in any  page that contains <img src='etc'> the working code is in my post above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173041/discussion-between-jose-carlos-ramirez-vasquez-and-danny-lee).

Answer (score 0):

Your frist method is  `$id_photo_directory = 'images/';` It seems your php code is outside of the images folders.

When you change `$id_photo_directory = '/it/webcam/member/images/';`, I thought the directory is wrong. If you want to put, you must create the folder it/webcam/memeber/images folder and your php code is must be outside of these folder.

Example: The structure must be like that.

- php file
- it > webcam > member > images

And also, should be like that `$id_photo_directory = 'it/webcam/member/images/';`

Comment: Thanks for your response but I don't want to do that submit.php/it/webcam/member/images/ I want the file call submit.php to stay where it is at /it/webcam/member/submit.php is it impossible to do that? Or do I need another method?

Comment: it only works with $id_photo_directory= 'images/'; this did not work with the dots method $id_photo_directory= '../images/'; or $id_photo_directory= '..images/'; I don't want to be able to be forced to move files around just to do this I like where the files are at I wonder how can I do that

Comment: and plus I need to get the full path of that photo with out errors so when I do use mysqli it will look this in a image tag regardless what file or folder it is in <img src='/it/webcam/members/example.png'>

Comment: If you did  /it/webcam/member/submit.php, you try to test $id_photo_directory = '';.

Comment: As per explaination, I thought you want to put image inside membre folder. Try to test with blank, $id_photo_directory = '';